# How to declare Constant Values in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to declare constants to be used in an array in JavaScript? I tried this but I get an error saying that Undefined Reference for the constant values in the array.

Here is my original code:

```
module.exports = {
    ADVICE:             'advice',
    APPROVE_ANY:        'approve_any',
    APPROVE_FIRST:      'first_reply',
    APPROVE_MAJORITY:   'approve_majority',
    APPROVE_UNANIMOUS:  'approve_unanimous',
    OBJECTION:          'objection',
    GRIPE:              'gripe',
    TELL:               'tell',
    SILENT:             'silent',
    DIALOG_TYPES:       ['advice', 'approve_any', 'first_reply', 'approve_majority', 'approve_unanimous', 'objection', 'gripe', 'tell', 'silent'],
    YES:                'yes',
    NO:                 'no',
    NO_REPLY:           'no_reply',
    RESPONSE_TYPES:     ['yes', 'no', 'no_reply'],
    MOBILE_PROVIDER:    ['AT&T', 'T-Mobile', 'Verizon']
}
```

Here is my code snippet (refactored):

```
module.exports = {
    ADVICE:             'advice',
    APPROVE_ANY:        'approve_any',
    APPROVE_FIRST:      'first_reply',
    APPROVE_MAJORITY:   'approve_majority',
    APPROVE_UNANIMOUS:  'approve_unanimous',
    OBJECTION:          'objection',
    GRIPE:              'gripe',
    TELL:               'tell',
    SILENT:             'silent',
    DIALOG_TYPES:       [ADVICE, APPROVE_ANY, APPROVE_FIRST, APPROVE_MAJORITY, APPROVE_UNANIMOUS, OBJECTION, GRIPE, TELL, SILENT],
    YES:                'yes',
    NO:                 'no',
    NO_REPLY:           'no_reply',
    RESPONSE_TYPES:     [YES, NO, NO_REPLY],
    MOBILE_PROVIDER:    ['AT&T', 'T-Mobile', 'Verizon']
}
```

Comment: That's not an array. And no, you cannot refer to other parts of an object inside its object initializer expression.

Comment: Where the error is occurring is an array.

Comment: Define the object members outside of the object; you can create the object programmatically by downcasing.

Comment: Note that your `DIALOG_TYPES` really wants to be a some kind of key/value mapping, not a straight array. There is nothing in your code to tell you what value DIALOG_TYPES[3] represents right now, other than "I just know", and that makes for imminent bugs later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties are not variables. They'll become variables in the file that imports from this, because it will use destructuring to declare the variables. But you can't refer to them that way inside the object itself.

What you can do is declare these as variables in your module, then export them all.

```
const ADVICE =             'advice',
      APPROVE_ANY =        'approve_any',
      APPROVE_FIRST =      'first_reply',
      APPROVE_MAJORITY =   'approve_majority',
      APPROVE_UNANIMOUS =  'approve_unanimous',
      OBJECTION =          'objection',
      GRIPE =              'gripe',
      TELL =               'tell',
      SILENT =             'silent',
      DIALOG_TYPES =       [ADVICE, APPROVE_ANY, APPROVE_FIRST, APPROVE_MAJORITY, APPROVE_UNANIMOUS, OBJECTION, GRIPE, TELL, SILENT],
      YES =                'yes',
      NO =                 'no',
      NO_REPLY =           'no_reply',
      RESPONSE_TYPES =     [YES, NO, NO_REPLY],
      MOBILE_PROVIDER =    ['AT&T', 'T-Mobile', 'Verizon']

module.exports = {
    ADVICE,
    APPROVE_ANY,
    APPROVE_FIRST,
    APPROVE_MAJORITY,
    APPROVE_UNANIMOUS,
    OBJECTION,
    GRIPE,
    TELL,
    SILENT,
    DIALOG_TYPES,
    YES,
    NO,
    NO_REPLY,
    RESPONSE_TYPES,
    MOBILE_PROVIDER
}
```

Comment: It appears the this will be the way to go for my first refactor pass.  It seems to maintain the least amount on changes that I have to hunt down in my downstream code.  I am doing things in verification and switch statements like the following:

Comment: `body('dialogType')    
        .exists()  
        .withMessage('dialogType field is required'). 
        .isIn(constants.DIALOG_TYPES)`

Comment: `switch(poll_type) {  case: constants.APPROVE_ANY }`

Comment: I might consider @pomax answer for a more complete refactor, but I think I would have to inspect a lot more downstream code to reference the right constant value.

Comment: The correct syntax is `case constants.APPROVE_ANY: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code currently has zero way to tell which array position in `DIALOG_TYPES` maps to which "actual thing", so you probably want to solve this first, and in doing so, almost certainly make your module export a little easier/cleaner:

```js
const DIALOGS = {
    ADVICE:             'advice',
    APPROVE_ANY:        'approve_any',
    APPROVE_FIRST:      'first_reply',
    APPROVE_MAJORITY:   'approve_majority',
    APPROVE_UNANIMOUS:  'approve_unanimous',
    OBJECTION:          'objection',
    GRIPE:              'gripe',
    TELL:               'tell',
    SILENT:             'silent',
};

const RESPONSES = {
    YES:                'yes',
    NO:                 'no',
    NO_REPLY:           'no_reply',
};

module.exports = {
  DIALOGS,
  DIALOG_TYPES: Object.values(DIALOGS),
  RESPONSES,
  RESPONSE_TYPES: Object.values(RESPONSES),
  MOBILE_PROVIDER: [
    'AT&T',
    'T-Mobile',
    'Verizon'
  ]
};
```

but even better: don't export `DIALOG_TYPES` and `RESPONSE_TYPES` at all, given that you can trivially get their values as array using `Object.values()` already. Just export `DIALOGS` and `RESPONSES` and have the downstream code decide whether they need a (temporary) values-only array  for something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will probably go with this solution in the long run.  But I need more time to inspect downstream code.